# How to create an object dynamically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a new object from an array of strings, but I'm not able to create the desired object correctly.

I'm trying to create an object like:

```
{
  "Employee1": {
    "id": "Employee1"
  },
  "Employee2": {
    "id": "Employee2"
  }
}
```

Here's my code:

```js
function listToItemById(qsList, key = "id") {
  const result = {};
  qsList.forEach((item) => {
    result[item][key] = item;
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(listToItemById(["Employee1", "Employee2", "Employee3", "Employee4", "Employee5", "Employee6", "Employee7", "Employee8"]));
```

Comment: Try changing the one line in the loop: `result[item] = {[key] : item};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

First, we have to set `result[item]` to `{}` (a new, empty object):

```js
function listToItemById(qsList, key = "id") {
  const result = {};

  qsList.forEach((item) => {
    result[item] = {};
    result[item][key] = item;
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(listToItemById(["Employee1", "Employee2", "Employee3", "Employee4", "Employee5", "Employee6", "Employee7", "Employee8"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
employes.reduce((obj, emp) => {
    if(typeof(obj) === "string") {
        var temp = {}
        temp[obj] = {id:obj}
        obj = temp;
    }
    obj[emp] ={id:emp};
    return obj;
})
```